# How to get signal strength from iphone and to publish the app in the App Store?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, signal-processing

Is there any way to get the quality of the signal from an iphone? I know that i can get this data from CoreTelephony framework, but it is an private framework and Not permitted such frameworks in the app store.

Someone can help me?

Thanks for all.

Best regards

Comment: you could always ask Apple to expose this functionality to developers via an enhancement request to http://bugreporter.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

You cannot currently get access to this information via a public api. Apple provides some sample code for checking if there is an internet connection and if the device is on wifi/cellular amongst other things. This is available at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

You could also try something really hacky like taking a screenshot and doing some image analysis on the top left corner of the screen to determine how many bars there are, if you're really keen..?